# CRM 2011: Silver light webresource to download email description

Tags: dynamic, silverlight-4.0, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, webresource

I want to use the silverlight as a web resource in CRM 2011 to download the description of the email activity as a word document. 
Please I want to know seek your kind help in this regard.

Comment: Please post a sample of the code you are trying to use and the issue you are encountering. There are plenty of samples of creating a Silverlight application for Dynamics CRM in the SDK and through a simple search of the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't recommend SL for CRM in general. Came across somewhere in the SDK where they say something like they are phasing out SL and the future is HTML (5 right now) + JS. (sorry, don't have a reference for that at hand but search the SDK). Why not use the built in export to excel functionality? Here's the quote but I forget where I read it but definitely some official MS statement:

*"Microsoft Silverlight web resources remain supported in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 and Microsoft Dynamics CRM Online for backwards compatibility. For components that will be able to be presented on all clients, we recommend using HTML web resources with HTML5 instead of Silverlight."*